# GLSL Project a full screen image onto a number of objects?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a fullscreen image that I want to directly project out onto a bunch of meshes.

Almost as though this fullscreen image were being rendered flat in screen space. But I only want it to appear on certain objects, out in enviroment, and also be occluded by certain objects.

So I want to somehow project this fullscreen image directly out and have it map onto whatever objects this shader on.

I can't quite get it right...

I have this so far:

```
varying mediump vec4 projCoord;     

#ifdef VERTEX     

    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;   
        mediump vec4 pos = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
        projCoord = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * pos;      
    }

#endif

#ifdef FRAGMENT

    uniform mediump sampler2D _ProjectTexture; 
    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = texture2DProj( _ProjectTexture, projCoord);
    }

#endif
```

It doesn't quite work. The projected image is too small, like 1/10th too small. it doesn't align with the full screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are your `#version` directives?  Or do you really want to use `110`?

Comment: This is actually code pulled out of unity shader, it's wrapped in ShaderLab syntax, which is why it is the way it is.

Comment: @genpfault Most probably, given all the other deprecated features used.

Comment: What does your texture matrix contain. As it currently stands it has to contain the transformation from the camera's view space into the post-projective space of the texture. If this is not the case (e.g. if it contains the transformation from world or object space into the post-projective texture space), then it won't work.